# Junit test Java static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm bit newbie to Java. Is it possible to Unit test scenario like this?

```
public class exampleClass {

    public static StatsDClient getClient() {
        return new NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder()
                .prefix("statsd1")
                .hostname("localhost")
                .port(4000)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that you want to test? In general, in this type of situation, you would just get call the static method, get the result, and test the result.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha Check whether this given object has the provided parameters inside it.

Comment: Well you have the client as a return value. Can you just check those values on the client? Like client.getHostname()

Comment: this NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder object doesn't have any getters. That's the problem

Comment: if `NonBlockingStatsDClientBuilder` is provided by a third-party library, then you don't need to test it. It should be tested by developer/author.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned the `StatsDClient` doesn't have any getters, can you override the `equals` method of `StatsDClient` something like this.
This way you'd not need getters

```
public class StatsDClient {
    private String hostName;
    private String prefix;
    private int port;
 
    public StatsDClient(String hostName, String prefix, int port) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        StatsDClient otherStatsClient = (StatsDClient) obj;

        return this.hostName.equals(otherStatsClient.hostName) && this.prefix.equals(otherStatsClient.prefix)
                && this.port == otherStatsClient.port;
    }
}
```

You can build expected `StatsDClient` and assert against the result

```
@Test
public void verifyStatsDClient() {
    StatsDClient actualStatsDClient = exampleClass.getClient();
    StatsDClient expectedStatsDClient = new StatsDClient("expectedHost","expectedPrefix",expectedPort);
    assertEquals(expectedStatsDClient,actualStatsDClient);
}
```

Since equals is overridden, `assertEquals` should implicitly calls the `equals` and verifies